# Change remote user in custom module

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm developing a custom network module for Ansible 2.5.2 for MikroTik RouterOS.

I want to change the remote username under the hood, e.g. if in my inventory I have `ansible_user: ansible`, I would like to change it to `ansible_user: ansible+cet`.

I have seen modules that do this in action plugins, like here: [CFSworks/ansible-routeros](https://github.com/CFSworks/ansible-routeros/blob/master/action_plugins/routeros.py#L56). 
However, it seems that in Ansible 2.5 with `network_cli` connection type this is no longer the case. When I add the following sample action plugin to `plugins/action` directory nothing happens – I don't see `routeros action plugin is called` in debug console:

```
class ActionModule(_ActionModule):

    def run(self, tmp=None, task_vars=None):
        display.debug('routeros action plugin is called')
        result = super(ActionModule, self).run(task_vars=task_vars)
        return result
```

This is my playbook:

```
- hosts: routeros
    gather_facts: no
    connection: network_cli
    tasks:
      - ...
```

And this is my inventory:

```
routeros:
  hosts:
    example:
      ansible_host: 192.168.88.1
      ansible_user: ansible
      # ansible_user: ansible+cet <-- i want to add '+cet' on the fly
      ansible_ssh_pass: ansible
      ansible_network_os: routeros
```

What is the proper way to replace the connection user in Ansible 2.5 with `network_cli` connection type?

Comment: @techraf I’ve tried adding debug logging into my action plugin, and log statements appeared after the connection was established.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. I have `connection: network_cli` specified in my playbook.

Comment: I see... You should add some code to the question.